# how can i make my visualforce custom buttons work?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a test visualforce page that I'm trying to get working. It's just a blank page with 2 buttons that should open the url in the iframe. Below is the code that I have behind the page.

Apex Class:

```
public class OnLoadController {

    public String Page {get; set;}
    public String OpenPageURL {get; set;}

    public void OnLoadController()
    {
        Page = '' ;
        OpenPageURL = '' ;
    }

    public PageReference redirect()
    {
        if(Page == 'google')
        {
            OpenPageURL = 'http://www.google.com' ;
        }
        if(Page == 'mpay')
        {
            OpenPageURL = 'http://www.yahoo.com/' ;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page id="pg" controller="OnLoadController">
<apex:form>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!redirect}" name="OpenPage" reRender="pb,theIframe">
    <apex:param assignTo="{!Page}" value="" name="param1"/>
</apex:actionFunction>


    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Google" onclick="OpenPage('google'); return false;"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Yahoo" onclick="OpenPage('blog'); return false;"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:iframe id="theIframe" src="{!OpenPageURL}" scrolling="true"/>

    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The page loads fine and the buttons show perfectly but when I click them nothing happens. I just want to be able to click the button and have the url open in the iframe of the page.

Comment: if(Page == 'mpay') and onclick="OpenPage('blog');

Answer (score 0):

Your apex code and visualforce are ok, but you need to look into the browser console where you can find the following errors:

> The page at 'https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/test' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.yahoo.com/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

After fixing this error you'll face the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=IhiYUoCsOcWdhAedlIKwDg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

As you understand it's security trouble.

This page will works fine `OpenPageURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' ;`